# useRef current getting its value only on second update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visnetwork

I have the following components:

```
const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const networkRef: any = useRef();

    // Somewhere in the code, I call this
    networkRef.current.filter(["id0, id1, id2"]);

    return (
    ...
        <VisNetwork 
            ref={networkRef}
        />
    ...
    )
}
export default ParentComponent;

interface Props {
    ref: any;
}
const VisNetwork: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef((props: Props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        filter(items: any) {
            setFilterNodes(items);
            nView.refresh();
        }
    }));

    const [filterNodes, setFilterNodes] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const filterNodesRef = useRef(filterNodes);
    useEffect(() => {
        filterNodesRef.current = filterNodes;
    }, [filterNodes]);

    ...
    // Some code to create the network (concentrate on the nodesView filter method)
    const [nView, setNView] = useState<DataView>();
    const nodesView = new DataView(nodes, {
        filter: (n: any) => {
            if (filterNodesRef.current.includes(n.id)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
    setNView(nodesView);
    const network = new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodesView, edges: edgesView}, options);
});
export default VisNetwork;
```

WHen I call `network.current.filter([...])`, it will set the `filterNodes` state.  Also, it should set the `filterNodesRef` inside the `useEffect`.

However, the `filterNodesRef.current` remains to be empty array.

But when I call `network.current.filter([...])` the second time, only then the `filterNodesRef.current` got the value and the `DataView` was able to filter.

Why is it like this? I thought the `useRef.current` will always contain the latest value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved this by calling the `refresh()` method inside the `useEffect` instead of the `filter()` method:

```
useEffect(() => {
    filterNodesRef.current = filterNodes;
    nView.refresh();
}, [filterNodes]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Settings the `.current` of a reference does not notify the component about the changes. There must be some other reason why it works the second time.

*From https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref*

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

You may want to use `useState`, as this does rerender the component.

#### Two more things

1. I'm not really sure what `networkRef.current.filter(["id0, id1, id2"])` is. Typescript does complain when I try to do `['a'].filter(['a'])` and I've never seen this, so are you sure this is what you wanted to do?
2. If you're passing references around there's probably a better way to do it. Maybe consider re-thinking the relations between your components. Are you doing this because you need access to `networkRef` inside multiple components? If yes, you might want to look at [providers](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

If this does not answer your question, write a comment (about something specific please) and I'll be happy to try and help you with it :)

Comment: i need to pass an array in `network.current.filter`, because the filter method in the `DataView` has this checking `filterNodesRef.current.includes(n.id)`

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev Am I correct in the assumption that this is not a standard array? Because if it is, you should be getting compiler errors.

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev Did it solve your problem otherwise?

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev then you should provide more detail about what your issue is :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `useRef.current` contains latest value, but your `filterNodesRef.current` in a `useEffect` that's why you get empty array in initial render.

- Initial render of `VisNetwork` the `filterNodes` is an empty array ==> `filterNodesRef.current` remains empty. Because `setFilterNodes(items);` is asyn function => event you set it in `useImperativeHandle` it will be updated in second render.
- In `useImperativeHandle` you set `setFilterNodes(items);` ==> filterNodes is updated and the `VisNetwork` re-render ==> `useEffect` is triggered ==> `filterNodesRef.current` is set to new `filterNodes`

Let's try this:

```js
.... 
const filterNodesRef = useRef(filterNodes);
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    filter(items: any) {
      filterNodesRef.current = filterNodes;
      setFilterNodes(items);
      nView.refresh();
    }
}));
...
```